# Is it possible to see which Groves Interlocks\Jettison switches I have already switched in System Shock 2023?

Tags: system-shock-2023

I'm coming back to System Shock (2023) after a short break, and I cannot remember which grove safety interlock\jettison switches I have already flipped.

Is there any way in game to tell, for example a status screen or log?

I don't want to have to go through all three groves again, especially Beta as I'm out of anti-toxin.